# Google scripts creating xml document from spreadsheet issue with adding content to root element

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I'm having an issue when trying to add content to the root element of an xml document I am creating in google apps script from a spreadsheet.  The error I am getting is Exception: Invalid argument: content (line 29, file "Code") which corresponds to where I try to do root.addContent(record).  Not sure why I cant add 'record', which is an Element, to 'root'.

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // This represents ALL the data
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var root = XmlService.createElement('feed');

  // This logs the spreadsheet in CSV format with a trailing comma
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var record = XmlService.createElement('record');
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        var uniqueId = XmlService.createElement('unique_id').setText(values[i][j]);
        record.addContent(uniqueId);
      }
      root.addContent(record);
    }
    var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
    var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
    Logger.log(xml);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After rearranging where I add to the root node, it is working.

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // This represents ALL the data
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var root = XmlService.createElement('klaviyo-feed');

  // This logs the spreadsheet in CSV format with a trailing comma
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var record = XmlService.createElement('record');
    root.addContent(record);
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        Logger.log(values[i][j]);
        var uniqueId = XmlService.createElement('unique_id').setText(values[i][j]);
        record.addContent(uniqueId);
      }
    }
  }
  var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
  var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
  Logger.log(xml);
}
```